# Subscribing to /me/account changes on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-webhooks

I'm trying to get notified whenever a user either creates or gains permission to manage a new page. I've noticed there isn't a way to subscribe updates on /:user_id/account since the User webhook only provides access to the fields displayed [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/user).

Is there any way to use webhooks to accomplish this?

Comment: No there is not.

Comment: Guess I'll have to use polling then. Thanks!